# correct way to have restful endpoints

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I have the following endpoints, and I want them to be more restful. (maybe one post only but I am not sure)

```
.route('/xyz/:testId/report')
.post( testController.generateReport)  //automatically create file and 
                                        //update database, is this can be a get? as user is not posting any data

.route('/test/:testId/report/upload')
.post( testController.upload)  // user-client posting a report
```

whats the best to remove

Comment: Not sure about what you're really after, but none of the APIs are RESTful. Have you read the REST guideline? What is `xyz`? What do you mean by "remove"?

Comment: Real example : (both are post routes)
 .route('/users/:userId/report') // this will use userId and server will generate a document and save it to database
 .route('/users/:userId/report/upload') // in this case user will actually post a data file

Comment: What is the goal of this question? I want to make sure that you get the help that you need with REST, but it seems like what you need the most is resources to show you the REST guidelines. Is that correct?

Comment: no not really, i am quite aware about rest in general, but for a particular situation, is it fair to use query params with POST in order to avoid having two seperate end point otherwise. i.e, POST /users/{id}/reports?type=upload POST /users/{id}/reports?type=generate vs POST /users/{id}/reports/upload POST /users/{id}/reports/generate (however i do understand @QualityCatalyst point as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST is *resource* based. Your two options have no resources in it and the APIs don't follow the guideline. It might pay to read it or run through a tutorial.

Posting a report RESTfully looks like this. Use plurals for your resources:

```
POST /users/{id}/reports
```

You select a specific user and post a new item into the `reports` collection. There is no such thing like action words in REST such as `upload` yet there are some edge situations when the guideline isn't specific enough and you may need to go down that path - typically in a `PATCH` case only.

Regarding POSTs and GETs: `GET` is used to *get* resources. Don't use it for creating data. `POST` is used to *accept* a resource you sent. `PATCH` is used to *change* an existing resource. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) for a simple explanation of all the HTTP verbs available.

Comment: POST /users/{id}/'reports' even when you have one report per user ?

Comment: Answer depends on a few things, but in short: yes, keep it `/reports`. If you do indeed have one report only you could go down calling it `/report` yet that causes confusion at the consumer side as resources are typically lists. If they contain one report or many, no one cares too much. `/report` would leave no room for extensions and requires you to document more than usual. You would also use a `PUT`, not a `POST`. Technically, you have many reports even though all of them have a unique user assigned. Think a little ahead and calls like `/reports?published=2018-02-13` could become useful.

Comment: that makes sense and i guess this is the answer, instead of two posts i would use query params and call appropiate controller method i.e, users/:userId/reports?upload=true or users/:userId/reports?generate=true

Comment: Well, as explained, that wouldn't be RESTful. Query parameter are typically used for queries (`GET`), rarely for overrides (`PUT`, `PATCH`). But not for a `POST`. I. e. `users/{id}/reports?upload=true` would be used exclusively for a `GET` and should return all reports that fulfill the filter criteria `upload=true`. There will be no data stored nor created. Avoid to use actions in your APIs such as `generate`. It isn't REST. It creates custom situations which are confusing and you need to explain well. You better stick with the guideline or your APIs may become hard to maintain quickly.